# Website Has SSL Issue, Shows in IE and Safari but Not Chrome or irefox

Tags: linux, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a website a company I freelance for took over and since it was transferred their site went down. The website is www.baseline-enserv.com.

For me, it shows up fine in Internet Explorer and safari but in Chrome and Firefox it's redirecting it to an https:// of which it is not.

I have checked the htaccess and it had a https redirect in there which i've removed. I did a database search and didn't find any URL's with https and I checked the wordpress settings for the site itself and it's set to http://.

I can't figure out where else to look to find out what's causing it to redirect. I even checked to see if there was a DNS setting that somehow did it but there is none.

It should NOT be redirecting to https but should be http only.

I also ran a test on geopeeker.com and to my surprise it checks out in all locations, but it may be using the same browser that i'm using that shows up fine.

I also have an account for browserstack so I have tested it on there and it checked out and loaded fine in Firefox 47 and 45, Windows 8 as well as Chrome 50 and 51.

It seems as if it's a caching issue but when I clear my cache and cookies it still doesn't work.

Thanks!

This is all that resides in the htaccess by the way.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

They had the site installed into a site folder in the root.

Comment: Was `Strict-Transport-Security` enabled on the previous SSL host?  This tells clients never to connect to the site over http even if requested.  If this was the case, you'll want/need to re-install an SSL cert on the site because any clients who had previously visited will suffer the same problem, their browsers will want to connect to https and the only way around it is to surf in private (there may be some tricks to delete the HSTS history for a site in a browser, but it's not something you can do on your end for your visitors.

Answer (score -1):

It is definitely a cache mechanise problem. Your site used to have a Permeant Redirect (301) rule in .htaccess. And that is being cached by the browser.

In Chrome, I don't think that "Clear browsing data" will be helpful in this case. There are some workarounds, I think that might help:

**For Chrome**:

- Try to use incognito mode for testing
- Try to open the inspector, and go to Settings (three dots on the right side) => check Disable cache (while DevTools is open), and reload the page.

**For Firefox**:

- Private tab will work fine
- Or you manually check cache file to make sure by accessing "about:cache"

If none of above work, try to put some random query string after the url for testing. For example:

*www.baseline-enserv.com/?test*

If it doesn't work too, I think you have to try it out on other machine/device. But after all, that cache will not last for long. And it will soon be cleaned. So, if it is no urgent, just sit back and get some coffee. And get back to it later.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It's weird, I gave this a trie. It does show up in private browsing for firefox but it doesn't in chrome with incognito and the disable cache button. It still redirects. I'm going to try the above solution of adding in an SSL since I told them it works for new people that haven't been to the site only you guys who frequent it does it not work. So we'll see how this works.